# Get information for Facebook page in Facebook API graph

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

I have a simple question in python.
If I have a Facebook page ID let say '6127898346' for example, how can I retrieve this page information such as (Likes count) , and store the result on a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use some sort of Facebook API package, like https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk available with `pip install facebook-sdk`.

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI()
page = graph.get_object('6127898346')
print '{} has {} likes.'.format(page['name'], page['likes'])
```

Easy way to save everything:

```
import json
with open('outf.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(page, f)
```

Comment: Thank you. Also if you dont mind. Why I can retrieve the people that like the page.

Comment: This gives an error: GraphAPIError: An access token is required to request this resource. 
Where to put this access token?

Comment: @rat http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#class-facebook-graphapi

Comment: I am genuinely confused about access_tokens. Are they same for different actions? Are they different? 

Anyway. Some codes in that doc don't work. For eg. the example for parameters give this error:

    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has updated their API and now the same requests would need access token. The graph API is also changed and to get likes count, you can do following:

```
def get_fb_page_like_count(fb_page_id)
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=your_access_token)
    args = {'fields': 'likes'}
    page = graph.get_object(fb_page_id, **args)
    return page.get('likes', 0)
```